# Нужно ли во всех подключаемых файлах использовать пространства имен?

Tags: php

Например, в файл index.php, у меня подключается файл config.php через require.

В файле, index.php у меня используется пространство имен: `use \MyNamespace\Data;`
также, это пронстраство имен используется в файле config.

Нужно ли в обоих файла писать `use \MyNamespace\Data;` ? или можно только в index.php?

Будет ли ошибкой, если для гибкости, напишу и в файле config, чтобы при подключении файла в другие файлы, небыло ошибок ?

Comment: Ну а зачем вы у нас спрашиваете? Спросите у php. Напишите, запустите. Если заработает, значит можно, если не заработает - нельзя

Comment: @samiy-slavniy Можно только в `index`, а можно и в `config`, так как он подключается в файл `index`. Вам необходимо чуть побольше прочитать про `require` и `include`. Это Вам даст больше информации и понимания, нежели мы просто Вам дадим готовый ответ. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.require.php   https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php